# Get original bytes from request

Tags: dart, aqueduct

How I get original bytes from request? Calling `request.body.asBytes()` I get this message:

`asBytes() expected list of bytes, instead got List<_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>>`

I saw that `HTTPRequestBody` has the property `retainOriginalBytes` to use in this case, but where I set it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a lager example of what you do, so it's possible to recreate it. I'd say that, at the very least, the error message should be better.

Comment: this message is thrown when `request.body.as Bytes()` is calling in anywhere of controller. Using `retainOriginalBytes` correctly resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Whatever endpoint you're hitting with your request is returning a Map in its body, not a list of Bytes.

I'm not sure if you can control the contents of what that endpoint is returning but if you can that would be the place to change it.

Check out the [BytesBuilder](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-io/BytesBuilder-class.html) class. Also, read the Aqueduct docs for [Request and Response Objects](https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/request_and_response/). Hopefully this gets you on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; this will work correctly once you've set `retainOriginalBytes` to true. This must be done before the body is decoded.

In an `HTTPController`, the request body is decoded before your method that handles the request is called. Just before the decoding, `HTTPController` calls its `willDecodeRequestBody()` method. This method does nothing by default, but you can override it to set `retainOriginalBytes`:

```
@override
void willDecodeRequestBody(HTTPRequestBody body) {
  body.retainOriginalBytes = true;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/stablekernel/pr_bot/blob/master/lib/controller/hook_controller.dart) is an example of an application that does this.